# Select text in href

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to know how to choose the text part in href.

HTML:

```
<li class="page-next">
    <strong href="1">next_page</strong>
</li>
```

Here is my code:

When I print `next_page_number`, the output is `1`

```
next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='page-next'][1]/strong")   
next_page_number = next.get_attribute("href")
print next_page_number  #output: 1
```

But when I use if else like below, It will output `1` and `no`
I don't know why it don't print `yes`

```
next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='page-next'][1]/strong")   
next_page_number = next.get_attribute("href")
print next_page_number  #output: 1
if next_page_number == 1:
    print 'yes'
    #next.click()
else:
    print 'no'
```

Please show me how to select the text in href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got *str* in *next_page_number* and try to equal it with number

```
next_page_number = '1'
print(next_page_number, type(next_page_number))  #output: 1, <class 'str'>
# set str explicit or call int(next_page_number)
if next_page_number == '1': 
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```